# How to prevent displaying double validation errors in CI?

Tags: php, codeigniter, validation

I'm setting the same callback function for multiple fields in my form:

```
foreach($fields as $class => $i)
{
    ++$i;
    $validation->set_rules('car_' . $i . '_one', $class, 'trim|xss_clean|callback_validate_car_fields[TRUE]');
    $validation->set_rules('car_' . $i . '_twor', $class, 'trim|xss_clean|callback_validate_car_fields[FALSE]');
    $validation->set_rules('in_car_' . $i . '_one', $class, 'trim|xss_clean|callback_validate_car_fields[TRUE]');
    $validation->set_rules('in_car_' . $i . '_two', $class, 'trim|xss_clean|callback_validate_car_fields[FALSE]');
}
```

(`class` variale is the `Car` in this case)

Here is the callback function:

```
function validate_car_fields($input, $required)
{

    if ($required === "TRUE" && empty($input))
    {
        $this->form_validation->set_message('validate_car_fields', 'Field %s can not be empty!');
        return FALSE;
    }

    return TRUE;
}
```

And it is showing the doubled errors:

```
* Field Car can not be empty!
* Field Car can not be empty!
* Field Car can not be empty!
* Field Car can not be empty!
```

It is understandable behaviour in this case, but I would like to show just one error per **field name**, instead of 4 for each field. How this can be done?

Comment: I'm confused - why are you setting the rule 4 times? Cant you just set it once and then use your callback to check for the 4 conditions?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this

```
function validate_car_fields($input, $required)
{
    static $validation_failed_once = FALSE;

    if ($required === "TRUE" && empty($input))
    {
        // Return FALSE without setting error message from 2nd validation fail onwards
        if ($validation_failed_once) return FALSE;

        $this->form_validation->set_message('validate_car_fields', 'Field %s can not be empty!');
        // Set error message only for the first validation error
        $validation_failed_once = TRUE;
        return FALSE;
    }

    return TRUE;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

It'd considering editing or creating ([Extending Native Libraries](http://codeigniter.com/user_guide/general/creating_libraries.html)) `libraries/MY_Form_validation.php` with a new function:

```
function remove_duplicate_errors() {

    $arr = array();
    foreach(array_keys($this->_error_array) as $h) {
        if (in_array($arr, $this->_error_array[$h]))
            unset($this->_error_array[$h]);
        else $arr[] = $this->_error_array[$h];
    }

}
```

And just call `$this->form_validation->remove_duplicate_errors();` after `$this->form_validation->run()` is made. This should remove all cases where the string is identical. But do consider another approach on your design, since it may be usefull to know which one of these 4 that's incorrect.